# Angular: Set size of input tag based on content length

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to set the size of the `input` tag in my html based on the size of the ng-model value.

I tried this

```
<span>Node Path:  
<input for="nodeName" type="text" ng-model="nodePath" size="{{nodePath.length()}}"ng-disabled="true">
</span>
```

but it throws this exception

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{nodePath.length()}}
TypeError: v2.length is not a function
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: string.length is a property, not a function. Remove the () in {{nodePath.length()}} ?

Comment: Have you tried {{ nodePath.length }} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: length is not a function.

Replace

```
{{notePath.length()}}
```

with

```
{{notePath.length}}
```